# Two logical operators for the disabling the button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Actually I know this is very basic question. But I am a bit confused so I am asking,

I have three conditions ,

which is like,

```
<button className="btn btn-primary fetchBtnSize" disabled={(this.state.disableFetch && this.state.disableHighetch && this.state.disableMidFetch)}>Fetch Questions</button>
```

So, Here what I want to do is that,

if all becomes false then I want to enable that button. But if any of them is true then the button should get disabled.

I know this is very basic but I tried, I am a bit confused so I am asking the question.

Comment: If any are true than it should be disabled? Than use or not and

Comment: It is just like @epascarello said :) `{(this.state.disableFetch || this.state.disableHighetch || this.state.disableMidFetch)}`

Answer (score 2):

Ternary operator should do the trick

```
 disabled={(this.state.disableFetch && this.state.disableHighetch && this.state.disableMidFetch)? true: false}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way would be to wrap your needs into a component and pass it the parent state:

```
const ConditionallyRenderedButton = (props) => {
  const { disableFetch, disableHighetch, disableMidFetch } = props;
  const isDisabled = !disableFetch && !disableHighetch && !disableMidFetch;

  return(
    <button className="btn btn-primary fetchBtnSize" disabled={isDisabled}>Fetch Questions</button>
  )
}
```